# Highlighting in VIM 6.3 -- need some adjustments

Tags: vim, vi

I'm on pretty old RedHat distribution with VIM-6.3 installed, and whenever I do search with "/" it highlights the text found in a very bright yellow color, so I'm unable to see the text under it. Is there a way to change the brightness to something more appropriate?

Comment: Not sure whether this is what you want, but you can turn off the search highlighting entirely with: `:set nohlsearch`, or temporarily (until the next search) with `:nohlsearch` (or just `:noh`).

Comment: I have to use some older Centos distros, which have the same version of Vim installed. Rather than subject myself to that, I grab the source to Vim, and compile a copy for my own use. Use `./configure PREFIX=$HOME/bin` when you configure it and it will install into your own home directory. Add `~/bin:` to the front of your path and the new vim will respond whenever you need it. Additionally, grab some colorschemes for Vim from vim.org. I favor "ir_black" on my Ubuntu guest in my Mac OS hosted VM, and "wombat" on my Linux boxes at work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Vim, try:`:hi Search ctermbg=Green`
With gVim: `:hi Search guibg=Green`
to set the background color to green, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked out for me:

:hi Search term=standout ctermfg=0 ctermbg=3


Now how to put this command in the configuration file?

Comment: ustra: that was simple!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use some different colorscheme, just type `:colorscheme` and then press TAB to go trough the various schemes.